# Проблема с sql запросом в intellij idea

Tags: sql, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Intellij Idea почему-то не знает о таких sql командах как Update и Delete, зато знает Insert и Select. При наведении на "ошибку" пишет

> statement expected, got Update

Кто-нибудь знает что это за настройка и как это поправить?

Comment: Неправильные кавычки?

Comment: @Kromster с кавычками точно всё нормально. Если удалить слово Update и нажать ctrl + space, то появится список ключевых слов для выбора, среди которых есть insert, select и нету update и delete